# Install OSX on Macbook Air which currently only runs Windows 7

Tags: macos, windows

I have a mac book air, which was formatted a long time ago, and only has windows running on it.

I would like to run Mac OS again instead of windows. Or if that isnt possible, have both OS's.

How can I get Mac OS installed on this machine again?

Comment: Though n1000's answer will work - it might just be worth checking by holding Opt at the boot chimes, just to see if any remnant of OS X is still on there. If so you could build from that rather than wipe & start over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use [OS X internet recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718):

1. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at startup
2. Open the disk utility from the opening menu
3. Reformat the disk to HFS+ Journaled
4. Close disk utility and go to install OS X

This procedure will delete all your data and Windows completely.